# Increasing compute power temporarily on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an Amazon EC2 Micro instance running using EBS storage.  This more than meets my needs 99.9% of the time, however I need to perform a very intensive database operation as a once off which kills the Micro instance.

Is there a simple way to restart the exact same instance but with lots more power for a temporary period, and then revert back to the Micro instance when I'm done?  I thought this seemed more than possible under the cloud based model Amazon uses but it doesn't appear to simply be a matter of shutting down and restarting with more power as I first thought it might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are manually running the database operation, then you can just create the image of the server, launch a small or a high cpu instance using the same image, run the database operation and then create the image and launch it again as a micro instance. You can also automate this process by writing scripts using AWS APIs.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using an EBS-backed AMI you don't have to create a new image and launch it. Just stop the machine and issue a simple EC2 API command to change the instance type:

```
ec2-modify-instance-attribute --instance-type <instance_type> <instance_id>
```

Keep in mind that not all instance types work for every AMI. The applicable instance types depend on the machine itself and the kernel. You can find a list of available instance types here: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Comment: Now that EC2 supports 64-bit for every instance type, this has become much more useful. Forget you ever knew about 32-bit instances.

Comment: I totally agree. I might also add, that you can now change the instance type directly in the AWS console by right-clicking an instance while it is stopped.